# Incorrect filename extension

Tags: apt, extension

In the Terminal whole doing `sudo apt-get update` I am often getting the message

```
ignoring 'get deb.list.bck in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d' as it has invalid filename extension
```

What is the correct extension?

Answer (score 5):

Check for the file ended with `deb.list.bck` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.If you found any then move it to another directory(Home).

It allow only the files ended with `.list`, `.list.save`, `.list.bak`.

**OR**

Try this simple command to move all the files ended with `.bck` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory to your `~/Desktop` directory.

```
sudo find /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ -type f -name "*.bck" -exec mv {} ~/Desktop \;
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a backup you made once of your `deb.list` file - even though I have checked and I don't have such a file in my setup - which explains the .bck extension.

Can you please confirm if you have a `deb.list` file in there?

Answer (score 0):

The correct extension is `.list` and `.list.save` (for backups).

Answer (score 0):

We can also fix this issue like this:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deb.list.bck /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deb.list
```